# Performance issue designing threaded consumer of queue

Tags: java, connection, queue, rabbitmq

I'm really new to programming and having performance problems with my software.  Basically I get some data and run a 100 loop on it(`i=0;i<100;i++`) and during that loop my program makes 1 of 3 decisions, keep the data its working on, discard it, or send a version of it back to the queue to process.  The individual work each thread does is very small but there's a lot of it(which is why I'm using a queue server to scale horizontally).

My problem is it never takes close to my entire cpu, my program runs at around 40% per core. After profiling, it seems the majority of the time is spend sending/receiving data from the queue(64% approx. in a part called `com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(DataInputStream)` and `com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame()`, 17% approx. is getting it in the format for the queue(I brought down from 40% before) and the rest is spend on my programs logic).  Obviously, I want my work to be done faster and want to not have it spend so much time in the queue and I'm wondering if there's a better design I can use.

My code is actually quite large but here's a overview of what it does:

1. I create a connection to the queue server(rabbitmq and java)
2. I fork as many threads as I have cpu cores(using the same connection)
3. Data from thread is
4. each thread creates its own channel to the queue server using the shared connection.
5. There'a while loop that pools the server and gets X number of messages without acknowledgments
6. Once I get a message, I use thread executor to send an acknowledge while my job is running
7. I parse the message and run my loop
8. If data is sent back to the queue, I send it to a thread executor that sends it back so my program can proceed with the next data set.

One *weird* thing I did, was although I use thread executor for acknowledgments and sending to the queue, my main worker thread is just a forked thread(using `public void run()`) because my program is dedicated to this single process I did that to make sure there was always X number of threads ready to work(and there was no shutting down/respawning of them). The rest is in threads because I figured the rest could wait/be queued while my main program runs.

I'm not sure how to design it better so it spends less time gathering/sending data.  Is there any designs, rabbitmq, Java things I can use to help?

Comment: How's the network load look during your run? If you connect to a server, you could be saturating the network channel much earlier than you can max out your CPUs.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight for my profiling tests all traffic is local(127.0.0.1).

Comment: Is the server grabbing data from a harddrive in order to provide data for your application, or writing logs? (hd throughput too low for cpu). This would be a similar situation as 'dasblinkenlight' describes. (performance can be said to be i/o bound)

Comment: @MartinK Good question, I *think* the way rabbitmq works is it keeps as much as it can in memory and if the queue gets too large it writes it to disk. I have plenty of memory so I doubt rabbitmq is touching HD a lot and my consumer program(the one I describe) does not do any disk I/O at all. Before I added the queue, it used 100% cpu.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not IO wait, then I suspect that it's down to some locking going on inside those methods.

It looks to me like your threads are spending a significant amount of time waiting for them to return. Somewhat counter-intuitively, you might well be able to increase your performance by cutting down on the number of threads, since they'll spend less time tripping over each other and more time actively doing something.

Give it a try and see what affect it has on the profile.